# glDrawElements() not working

Tags: c++, opengl, draw

This has been bothering me for the last days and I can't figure out why.
I know there are a lot of questions like this one here on stackoverflow but none seem to solve my issue.

So here it is the initialization code:

```
GLuint EBO[1];
GLuint VAO[1];
GLuint VBO[1];

static vec2 tri_pos[8] = { 
{-1.0f, -1.0f},
{-1.0f, -1.0f},
{-1.0f,  1.0f},
{-1.0f,  1.0f},
{ 1.0f, -1.0f},
{ 1.0f, -1.0f},
{ 1.0f,  1.0f},
{ 1.0f,  1.0f} };

static GLuint tri_indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };

glGenBuffers(1, EBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tri_indices), tri_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glCreateVertexArrays(1, VAO2);
glBindVertexArray(VAO2[0]);

glCreateBuffers(1, VBO2);
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, VBO2[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tri_pos), tri_pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
```

Here I create the buffers and bind them accordingly. I create the VAO, the VBO and the Element Buffer Object.
Then I assign the `tri_pos` array to a `vec4` in the shader and enable it.

After that I call the `draw()` function to draw the triangles in this case:

```
//...

glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, cColor);

glBindVertexArray(VAO2[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, VBO2[0]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 5, 3);
//glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 1);
//glMultiDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, tri_indices, count, 2);
```

Here I use `glDrawElements()` with `nullptr` because Im using a EBO.

Everything compiles just fine. But at runtime it just crashes. I have no clue what I am missing. All the buffers seem me about right.

Anyone got any clue?

Comment: "it just crashes"  Which line crashes?

Comment: The line where `glDrawElements()` is at makes the program crash.

Comment: Have you noticed that tri_pos[0] == tri_pos[1]? No possible triangle with two identical vertices.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, VAO2);
```

You are creating a buffer but you probably want to create a vertex array:

```
glCreateVertexArrays(1, VAO2);
```

Also replace these calls:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, VBO2[0]);
```

with:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2[0]);
```

Comment: Indeed it was. Corrected it! Anyways the application keeps crashing.